# How can I embed a windows system terminal/console in a PyQt GUI Application?

Tags: python, console, pyqt, pyqt4

im trying to have a console inside the pyqt gui i have been working on this for so long trying so many different things and trying to explain it to so many people  here is what i need.

i am looking to create a cmd inside of my Pyqt4 Gui. like shown in this picture
MIND YOU this is just me moving the cmd from the program into the gui. in the picture below i have scribbled out with a red pen the boarder of the cmd(from the pythonw program) to show that i am looking to have the cmd inside not actually have the boarder. basically summed up i need a console embedded into the gui. that i can run commands threw it (NOT A PYTHON SHELL) only from the main code. my brain cant take the pain anymore and my tylenol is almost gone just from this one project. if some python master who thinks they could do this and would be willing to create this for me. i would appreciate it so much

if you want me to explain it to you in person you can join my discord server i will be here all day https://discord.gg/s63ZxTt

[image]

Comment: So I just googled "terminal in PyQt" and got a page of various results. Assuming you've tried these, could you add a bit of detail as to why they don't work or suit your needs? Specific examples of things you've tried but didn't work (and why) will go a long way towards getting you a workable answer.

Comment: @three_pineapples i have looked at all of these posts and they are not working for me. half of them the people even say they only work for os x and linix i use windows

Comment: I've updates your title so it is more clear what you are after. Hopefully someone can help you! Unfortunately I don't know how to do it on windows.